# Capture a copy of a website and then serve it

Tags: html, mirror, static-site

I'm aware of HTTRack, but it doesn't fit my need:

I wonder if there's a program I can run to capture a complete copy of a dynamic site such that I can then serve it on a static server? I know javascript-heavy pages could be complicated to do that with.

Basically I can see this working as follows:

Step 1. fetch all the linked assets starting from a particular URL and recreate the directory structure

Step 2. open each fetched html file in a headless browser and then convert the DOM to html and then overwrite the original html file

Comment: Have you had a look at [wget](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget)?

Comment: @IanBrindley — No good: "javascript-heavy pages"